# Matching everything between two HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, traversal, jquery-traversing

I have empty `<span>` elements that can be anywhere in the DOM. They have a specific *class* and *id* like `<span class="start" id="V.64"/>` and `<span class="end" id="V.64.end"/>`. So I can identify the starting point and the endpoint via the *id*. I now want to highlight everything that is in between those two `<span>`Elements. Is there any way to do that with jQuery?

EXAMPLE HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="upper-case">
        <b>In Matutinis</b>
        <span class="ab">
            <b data-toggle="tooltip">INV</b>
            <i class="incipit">Rex noster</i>. <span class="phenomena">*</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ab">
            <span class="start" id="V.112"/>
        </span>
        <span class="ab">In Secundo Nocturno <b data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title=""
                title="">AN</b>
            <i class="incipit">Nox praecessit</i>. <span class="end" id="V.112.end"/><b
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">RP</b>
            <i class="incipit">Civitas Hierusalem</i>.
                <i class="incipit"
                >Sicut mater</i>. <b data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title=""
                >RV</b>
            <i class="incipit">Deus a Libano veniet</i>. <span class="start" id="V.114"/>
        </span>
        <span class="ab">In Tertio Nocturno
                <span class="end" id="V.114.end"/>
            <b data-toggle="tooltip">EV</b>
            <i class="incipit">Erunt signa in sole</i>. <b data-toggle="tooltip">RP</b>
        </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

Note that the start and end spans can be anywhere in the DOM. Not just siblings! Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: We have to **wrap** the content between `<span class="start" id="V.64"/>` and `<span class="end" id="V.64.end"/>` in another `<span>` and give them background. Is that you need.?

Comment: Your HTML Code is not W3C conform, you do not want to have an opening `<span/>` like you can do with inputs. Overthink your DOM-structure, maybe add classes to the elements you'd expect to be highlighted at once.

Comment: You can't wrap anything that is on different hierarchical levels in the DOM. And I want to add classes to the elements that need to be highlighted but I have to find out which elements these are, that's the core question. I cannot change the DOM structure however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible using **.nextUntil()**

e. g.

```
var everythingInBetween = $('#V\\.64.start').nextUntil('#V\\.64.end').andSelf();
```

Note that you will have to escape the "." in the id-selector.